# What is wrong with this MySQL query (formatting left join)?

Tags: mysql

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT 
staff_names.staff_ID AS sid
staff_names.name AS name,
staff_names.rec_type AS rec_type,
prod_staff.specialized AS specialized,
compspec.name AS compspec_name
FROM staff_names JOIN prod_staff USING (staff_ID)
LEFT JOIN (prod_staff_compspec JOIN company_list USING (comp_ID)) compspec
USING (prod_ID, staff_ID, role_ID)
WHERE prod_staff.role_ID = 2
AND prod_staff.prod_ID = 27
AND prod_staff.asst = 'n'
AND episode IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY name
```

Running this as-is says there's an error near the 'compspec' alias. Removing that and changing 'compspec' to 'company_list' in the SELECT clause returns no rows, even though it should return 1 with the given values. The left join seems to be the problem, but I don't how it should be formatted.

The prod_staff table has prod_ID, staff_ID and role_ID fields. prod_staff_compspec has these and a comp_ID field. prod_staff may or may not have a matching prod_staff_compspec row, but prod_staff_compspec always has a matching company_list row.

What I want to do is retrieve a list of all staff names associated with a given role_ID and prod_ID in the prod_staff table, as well as a company name from the company_list table, if a link to such exists in the prod_staff_compspec table (only a small minority have one).

Answer (score 0):

Switched to `ON` to define the table relations. `LEFT JOIN (prod_staff_compspec JOIN company_list USING (comp_ID)) compspec` is switched to 2 `left join`.

```
select a.staff_id sid, a.name, a.rec_type, b.specialized, d.name compspec_name
from staff_names a
join prod_staff b on a.staff_id = b.staff_id
left join prod_staff_compspec c on b.prod_id = c.prod_id and b.staff_id = c.staff_id and b.role_id = c.role_id
left join company_list d on c.comp_id = d.comp_id
where b.role_id = 2 and b.prod_id = 27 and b.asst = 'n' and episode is not null
order by a.name;
```